# Multiple revisions of dts files in Linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have observed that in Linux kernel 4.1.15, there are dts files with multiple revisions as follows

```
s5p6818-artik710-raptor-rev03.dts
s5p6818-artik710-raptor-rev01.dts
s5p6818-artik710-raptor-rev00.dts
```

What is the purpose of these various revisions??

Comment: I'm pretty sure those revisions are about board revision and one has to choose the best fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to say without seeing the sources (these device trees are not part of the upstream kernel) but they are certainly to support different hardware revisions of the board. Some parts may have changed or some SoC pins have been routed differently.

Comment: The thing I am trying to accomplish is to add the support of led's in the dts file. I have added the required piece of code in the common .dtsi file but to no avail. I thought the multiple revisions might have something to do with it.